# Difference between cons and list function call in elisp

Tags: elisp, emacs24

In elisp,

```
(cons 1 2) `returns`
(1 . 2)
(list 1 2) `returns`
(1 2)
```

What is the difference between both the outputs?

Comment: The first is a single cons cell, the second is a list made up of two cons cells linked to each other.

Comment: in the first case, isn't '1' the first cons cell with '2' as its cdr & '2' - the second cons cell with nil cdr? what do you mean when you say, it is a single cons cell?

Answer (score 4):

`(cons 1 2)` creates a single cons cell like this:

```
---------  
| 1 | 2 |   
---------
```

Lists in Lisp are a chain of cons cells. Each cell's `car` is a list element, its `cdr` points to the next cell in the chain; the last one's `cdr` points to the special symbol `nil`. So `(list 1 2)` creates a chain of cons cells like this:

```
--------|   --------|
| 1 | ----->| 2 | ----> nil
--------|   --------|
```

It's equivalent to `(cons 1 (cons 2 nil))`

Answer (score 1):

If you have two things, `A` and `B`, you have as a given that `(eq (car (cons A B)) A)` and `(eq (cdr (cons A B)) B)`. That is, `cons` constructs a "cons cell" (a pair) with two parts, the `car` part and the `cdr` part.

By convention, a pair that consists of an atom and the empty list is considered to be a list. So, `(cons 2 nil)` is `(2)`. By that same token, `(list 1 2)` returns a similar structure to `(cons 1 (cons 2 nil))` (that is, `(1 2)`).

Answer (score 0):

the job of cons is to add the first element to the second element
so, in your first example `(cons 1 2)` the 2 is an element so adding 1 to it will create a pair `(1 . 2)`

the second example creates a list with 1 and 2 as element of that list

if it was like `(cons 1 (list 2))` now cons will find that the second parameter is a list and the result will be `(1 2)`